# IMO Question Six with a difference

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

In 1988, the International Mathematical Olympiad (IMO) featured this as its final question, Question Six:

> Let \$a\$ and \$b\$ be positive integers such that \$ab + 1\$ divides \$a^2 + b^2\$. Show that \$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}\$ is the square of an integer.

([IMO problems](https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx))

This can be proven using a technique called [Vieta jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping). The proof is by contradiction - if a pair did exist with an integer, non-square \$N=\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}\$ then there would always be a pair with a smaller \$a+b\$ with both \$a\$ and \$b\$ positive integers, but such an infinite descent is not possible using only positive integers.

The "jumping" in this proof is between the two branches of the hyperbola \$x^2+y^2-Sxy-S=0\$ defined by \$S\$ (our square). These are symmetrical around \$x=y\$ and the implication is that if \$(A,B)\$ is a solution where \$A\ge B\$ then \$(B,SB-A)\$ is either \$(\sqrt S,0)\$ or it is another solution (with a smaller \$A+B\$). Similarly if \$B\ge A\$ then the jump is "down" to \$(SA-B,A)\$.

#### Challenge

Given a non-negative integer, \$n\$, determine whether a pair of positive integers \$(a,b)\$ with \$n=|a-b|\$ exists such that \$ab+1\$ divides \$a^2+b^2\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to write the shortest code in bytes that your chosen language allows.

Your output just needs to differentiate between "valid" \$n\$ and "invalid" \$n\$, some possible ways include the below, feel free to ask if unsure:

- Two distinct, consistent values
- Truthy vs Falsey using your language's definition (either way around)
- A solution if valid vs something consistent and distinguishable if not
- Return code (if using this be sure that errors are not due to resource limits being hit - your program would still need to produce the expected error given infinite time/memory/precision/etc)

#### Valid inputs

Here are the \$n\lt 10000\$ which should be identified as being possible differences \$|a-b|\$:

```
0 6 22 24 60 82 120 210 213 306 336 504 720 956 990 1142 1320 1716 1893 2184 2730 2995 3360 4080 4262 4896 5814 6840 7554 7980 9240
```

For example \$22\$ is valid because \$30\times 8+1\$ divides \$30^2+8^2\$ and \$|30-8| = 22\$
...that is \$(30, 8)\$ and \$(8, 30)\$ are solutions to Question Six. The first jumps "down" to \$(8, 2)\$ then \$(2, 0)\$ while the second jumps "down" to \$(2, 8)\$ then \$(0, 2)\$.

---

Note: One implementation approach would be to ascend (jump the other way) from each of \$(x, 0) | x \exists [1,n]\$ until the difference is greater than \$n\$ (move to next \$x\$) or equal (found that \$n\$ is valid). Maybe there are other, superior methods though?

Comment: [The Return of the Legend of Question Six - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Vj_7Y2-xY) and [The Notorious Question Six (cracked by Induction) - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcaYEaVTA4g).

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=1:a>n+1or(n*n-2)%~(a*(a+n))*f(n,a+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoMwEAXQq8ymMJMomIobIb1IcTHSxgb0J4Rs3PTq0bd@@ay/hLG14Hc91o8SOvVu1hesS4Vh0D/l8Wc1rBYiJvA9rJOWS0TlNyikQqAIKorty9MwCMVASJXuLIu0Cw)

Outputs Truthy/Falsey reversed.

Checks whether $$\frac{n^2-2}{a(a+n)+1}$$ is ever an integer for any \$a\$ with \$1 \leq a \leq n+1\$. This upper bound suffices because for \$ a \geq n > 1 \$, the denominator is larger than the numerator, and for \$n=0\$ we just need to get a positive on \$a=1\$.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

*-4 bytes with the formula used in [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251895/58563)*

Returns either 0 (falsy) or a positive integer (truthy).

```javascript
f=(n,a=n)=>(n*n-2)%~(a*(a+n))?f(n,a-1):a|!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrBDoIwEAV/ZT1Adqk1xSNY/ZZNpUZD3hIwnoy/XultMjMv/eiW1ufy9rD7VEqOjKNGSLwyOvizND/WjtVB5JZr9L0M@j2gZFsZFCmMBLpQH0Il54T2T6htKRk2m6fTbI/dlD8)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
a;f(n){for(a=0;a++<=n&&(n*n-2)%~(a*(a+n)););a-=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVF/T4MwEP1/n@Ik2dLyI0KBQWXVP4yfwi2mYWUStVuAROKCH128wsa2Jr28e713vb7m3i7P@15mBdH0WOwrIoWfScdZCb1YEG1rj9H5L5E2kY6mNKOZ9ITOur7UDXzJUhMKxxngMkSj6uZNgwA/mzjVHlTeqO3rBvmj78LSBcZwRwgxTREHDAELhhC6EPpYE4YYYh@rEnPKY0w5RxQEkZGEhg2SAOkg5aGRpljMktC04TweWiCO/NREtkRVlHLTNQ3M5WmEfBLH5gpuajiL/G6cPN/ruoH8XVY2RpV/qGp8gLVuX9i65c@4Y8uF6zy0Tmo0Eoh5fKm3qh38OMEV1OWP2hfkbAu9PxH2xGR0aDLaOlmLXUZ7sxu@Rr4gDYU7Aez2SBkJCHH5gmGGDTyB4wwQrYOH82eZdahQWBBrvgXvETDO67XGVzYu1O5kRC2E2tCLynGuJ@tmXf@XF59yV/fe9z8)

*Port of [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251895/9481).*

Returns \$2\$ for invalid and an integer less than \$2\$ for valid.

Answer (score 2):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
lfsIc-*QQ2h*T+QTSh
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=lfsIc-%2aQQ2h%2aT%2BQTSh&input=1000&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A5%0A5%0A6%0A21%0A22%0A23%0A24&debug=0)

A naïve implementation of the algorithm layed out in [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s answer. I'll see if I can get a better score later.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 33 bytes

```
n->n*prod(a=1,n,n^2%(1+a*a+=n)-2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWNxXzdO3ytAqK8lM0Em0NdfJ08uKMVDUMtRO1ErVt8zR1jTQhCvcWFGXmlWhE59Xk2ehGG-jpGRoYGMTqKKZp5GnGQtUsWAChAQ)

A port of [@pajonk's R port](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251911/9288) of [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251895/9288). Returns falsy when there is a solution.

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 40 bytes

```
n->sumdiv(n^2-2,d,d--*issquare(n^2+4*d))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWNzXydO2KS3NTMss08uKMdI10UnRSdHW1MouLC0sTi1JBgtomWimamhD1ewuKMvNKNKLzavJsdKMN9PQMDYAgVidNI08zFqpmwQIIDQA)

Longer but faster. Checks if there is a divisor \$d>1\$ of \$n^2-2\$ such that \$n^2+4d-4\$ is a square.

Returns truthy when there is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
nÍILDI+*>Öà
```

-2 bytes porting [*@xnor*'s formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251895/52210) as well

Outputs `1`/`0` as truthy/falsey respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/73Cvp4@Lp7aW3eFphxf8/29pZGIAAA) or [verify the range [0,100]](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X@xyc3PXknhUdskBSV7P5f/eYd7/Xxc/LS17A5PO7zgv85/AA).

**Original 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach:**

```
L©+®ø.ΔnOyP>Ö
```

Outputs a valid pair as truthy or `-1` as falsey.

If looping indefinitely would have been a valid falsey result, `L©+®` could have been `∞+∞` instead for -1 byte.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59BK7UPrDu/QOzclz78ywO7wtP//LY1MDAA) or [verify the range [0,100]](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX/0YJGTj8iIOKGkiAiP05E/0zCqSvCrsO4Ls6Ubk95UD7Dlv99LP8).

**Explanation:**

Uses formula \$n^2-2 = 0 \mod a(a+n)+1\$ on the range \$[1,n]\$.

```python
n           # Square the (implicit) input-integer n
 Í          # Decrease it by 2
  IL        # Push a list in the range [1, input n]
            # (note: n=0 will become list [1,0])
    D       # Duplicate it
     I+     # Add input `n` to each value in the copy
       *    # Multiply the values at the same positions in the lists together
        >   # Increase each by 1
         Ö  # Check for each value in the list if it evenly divides the n²-2
          à # Check if any is truthy
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Creates a list of pairs \$[a,b]\$ where \$a\$ is in the range \$[n+1,2n]\$ and \$b\$ in the range \$[1,n]\$, and does the check defined in the challenge description on each pair: \$(a^2+b^2) = 0 \mod (ab+1)\$.

```python
L           # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer n]
            # (note: n=0 will become list [1,0])
 ©          # Store this list in variable `®` (without popping)
  +         # Add the (implicit) input to each value in the list
   ®ø       #  Pair it with list [1,n] of variable `®`
            # (we now have a list of pairs [a,b], where `a` is in the range [n+1,2n] and
            # `b` in the range [1,n] and |a-b|==n)
.Δ          # Pop and find the first pair of this list which is truthy for,
            # resulting in -1 if none are truthy:
  n         #  Square the values in the pair
   O        #   Sum them together
    y       #   Push the pair again
     P      #  Take the product
      >     #  Increase it by 1
       Ö    #  Check if (a²+b²) is divisible by (a*b+1)
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 35 bytes

```
\(n,a=1:n)all(n^2%%(a*(a+n)+1)-2)&n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU9RasMwDP3vKTJGhrU6YMl2YhVyk1IwZaGFYELSMXaW_WSDHWifu82kdAY_P0nvPeGPz3n9Gvrv19vQpN_Hoyk293gokMfRlBPVtcnPJu8L7BEagqfyL_0x88vSv12u54t5WPI0je_GHdDJsQNAg7DbaYaq-rNxtmptRSQ3CJUyCUcSQriBt5V3ovFeIDpRdTrlKCWzMMSgFq9d7FDamNirNYmYOq8xzHGLEB5cUqRWXCGxpibU5SlIv4tRV7BqmIIDuH9sXe_vHw)

Outputs reversed `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

Slight modification of [@xnor's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251895/55372): checks whether
$$ n^2 = 2 \mod a(a+n)+1.$$
This needs handling \$0\$ as a special case (`&n`), so we may check \$a\$ only up to \$n\$.

---

Actually a direct port works for the same byte-count:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org), 35 bytes

```
\(n,a=1:n)all((n^2-2)%%(a*(a+n)+1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU9bCgIxDPz3FCsipNqFJm3dRtibiFDERWFZxAfiWfxZBQ_kp7cx8VHodJLMTOj1tu_vTf04HZsyvUYL6Gyucd6Z3LYA3ZJKMuMx5AnkaWemaMxP-oT9-lCfN9vVBoaHvNu1F3BzdHJsY0yJZjDQDFXVK3C2mNmCSG4QKmUSjiSE8APeFt6JxnuB6ERV6ZSjlMzCEINavHaxQmljYq_WJGKqvMYwx0-E8OCSIs3EFRJrakJdnoL0qxh1BauGKbj_x_r--74B)

It's because for \$n=0\$ `a=1:n` becomes `[1 0]`, so we actually check \$a\$ up to \$n+1\$ for \$n=0\$, and up to \$n\$ for \$n>0\$, which is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
->n{(0..n).any?{|a|(n*n-2)%~(~a*~a+=n)==0}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNATy9PUy8xr9K@uiaxRiNPK0/XSFO1TqMuUasuUds2T9PW1qC29n@BAkilqYGBpl5xak5qcomGWprmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Ｎθ⊙…·¹⊕θ¬﹪⁻×θθ²⊕×ι⁺ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9DsIwEIN3niLjRQoDWTsxdmhVIV4gpCeIlFzIXyWePhxlqhdL/mzbl8k2Gt/7SO9W5xYemCHJ4bRkRxWu9IGRrG/FbXgz9ES4KMFJxoBUceWuVGKOFaa4Nh9hctQK3F3AAkmJxFTL4@QPnRIL//6cP3YNvWvdz5v/Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for valid, nothing if invalid. Explanation: Uses @xnor's algorithm. I tried writing it using vectorisation but that weighed in at 27 bytes:

```
Ｎθ¬Π﹪⁻×θθ²⊕÷⁻Ｘ⁺θ⊗⊕…⁰⊕θ²×θθ⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsIwEETvfkWPG6ggxVuvveTQEoo/kCaLBpKNSZP6@TFWQV0YhmVn3qqbjMpLWwqne05TdgtGCKw/iGgoweQTiOh1VgnGatbDaCivcDEOVwhtE1jbdFWcVESHlFADpzSYzWj8hIV/VKqweW8MPi92T30bs6QrwukfE9hr3viff3U77xfWl9J15bjZJw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                          Input `n` as a number
       θ                    Input `n`
      ×                     Multiplied by
        θ                   Input `n`
     ⁻                      Minus
         ²                  Literal integer `2`
    ﹪                       Vectorised modulo by
               θ            Input `n`
              ⁺             Vectorised plus
                  …         Range from
                   ⁰        Literal integer `0` to
                     θ      Input `n`
                    ⊕       Incremented
                 ⊕          Vectorised incremented
                ⊗           Vectorised doubled
             Ｘ              Vectorised raise to power
                      ²     Literal integer `2`
            ⁻               Vectorised subtract
                        θ   Input `n`
                       ×    Multiplied by
                         θ  Input `n`
           ÷                Vectorised divided by
                          ⁴ Literal integer `4`
          ⊕                 Incremented
   Π                        Take the product
  ¬                         Is zero (i.e. was any remainder zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 38 bytes

```
3 :'*/0<1|(_2+*:y)%1+(a+y)*a=.1+i.1+y'
```

Uses @xnor's formula, but implements it directly on an array containing a from 1 to n+1.

[Try it here](https://jsoftware.github.io/j-playground/bin/html2/#code=NB.%20Character%20count%0A%23%273%20%3A%27%27*%2F0%3C1%7C%28_2%2B*%3Ay%29%251%2B%28a%2By%29*a%3D.1%2Bi.1%2By%27%27%27%0ANB.%20indices%20for%20numbers%20not%20complying%20%3C%2010000%0AI.-.3%20%3A%27*%2F0%3C1%7C%28_2%2B*%3Ay%29%251%2B%28a%2By%29*a%3D.1%2Bi.1%2By%27%220%20i.%2010000%0ANB.%20note%3A%20I.-.%20just%20converts%20location%20in%20the%20array%20i.%2010000%20back%20to%20the%20number%0ANB.%20and%20%220%20is%20just%20for%20the%20function%20to%20take%20one%20at%20a%20time%0A)